# Write to stderr

Tags: bash, stderr

I'm using [stderred](https://github.com/sickill/stderred) to color all output streamed to stderr red. It's working fine. But when I write my own bash script and throw an error with `echo 'error' 1>&2`, it doesn't color the output in red. I reckon this is, because the command simply redirects the output to wherever the stderr file descriptor points to, but doesn't properly mark the message as belonging to stderr. Is that so? How can I properly write to stderr in bash?

Comment: for the record, you can also do `>&2 echo error` according to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23550347/247623).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears that the program is re-writting the various write() functions to detect whether you are printing to file descriptor 2 and then adding the relevant escape codes to make the output red at the terminal.

Unfortunately, in shell, when you do something like

```
echo "foo" 1>&2
```

The function will still be calling write (or some other similar system call) on file descriptor 1.  The output appears on fd 2 since file descriptor 1 has been dupped to file descriptor 2 by your shell.

Unfortunately, I don't know of way to write /directly/ to fd 2 in shell, but you can use awk.  A function like this will write the arguments directly to file descriptor 2.

```
error() {
  awk " BEGIN { print \"$@\" > \"/dev/fd/2\" }"
}
```

I believe this is a feature of GNU awk that isn't part of POSIX but it also works on the awk provided on OS X.

Comment: Sounds like `stderred` is a nice idea implemented wrong. The approach I would have taken would be to create a new `pts` device and connect file descriptor `2` to that. Then a it could have a process read the data written to that file descriptor and rewrite it to the original `pts` with escape codes included. Then it wouldn't have needed to use `LD_PRELOAD`, and `1>&2` would have worked. (My approach probably wouldn't have been entirely without problems either, but I think it would have worked better.)

Answer (score 4):

That software hooks the `write()` system calls that apprear to write at file descriptor 2, that is known as `stderr`.

It is a shared library (so recompilation of the kernel is not necessary). As descripted in the installation manual it takes use of the environment varaible `LD_PRELOAD`. The dynamic linker can be influenced into modifying its behavior during the program's execution. These variables adjust the runtime linking process by searching for shared libraries at alternate locations.

The executable `/bin/bash` itself does not honour such variables, so `bash` itself uses the original pallette of system calls, not the modified ones. The redirection you mentioned in your question happend in `bash`. Not in the executable of `echo`. If `echo` could wirte to the error descriptor by itself (not via bash) the output would be red.

Python can write to `stderr`. See the proof (that should appear in red):

```
python -c 'import os; os.write(2, "error")'
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a helper function:

```
echoerr() { printf "\033[0;31m%s\n\033[0m" "$*" >&2; }
```

And use it anywhere:

```
echoerr "something went wrong here"
```

This combines writing to stderr (`>&2`) and changing colors (solution taken from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947742/how-to-change-the-output-color-of-echo-in-linux).

Comment: You may want to test whether the standard error goes to a terminal before doing colour output.

Comment: @Kusalananda TBH, I don't know how to do that, so I did not. Also, it's a function, so the real destination can change. Considering the question asked, not sure overall, could be just fine.

Comment: @Kusalananda Does the following check look good to you? `echoerr () {
 if [[ $(tty -s) -eq 0 ]]; then
  printf "\033[0;31m%s\n\033[0m" "$*" >&2;
 else
  printf "%s\n" "$*" >&2;
 fi
}`

Comment: @dotnetCarpenter, if you want to test for `tty`, then you should rather write `if tty -s; then ......`   otherwise sounds good. Printing colors might be useful even outside of a tty context though, such as to a log file to be later viewed with `less -R`

Comment: @dotnetCarpenter `[ -t 2 ] && printf ... >&2`  See `man test`.

Comment: @VasyaNovikov good point about `less -R` and never seen an if statement without `test`, `[]` or `[[]]`. I didn't know that was allowed syntax :)

Comment: @Kusalanada `-t FD  file descriptor FD is opened on a terminal`. I get that `1`= `stdin`, `2` = `stdout` and `3` = `stderr` but I have never seen that outside pipes - ala `>&`... Where is the documentation for that? Can I use 123 as a reference to those file descriptors anywhere outside arithmetic expansion?

Comment: @dotnetCarpenter That's 0 for standard input and 1 and 2 for standard output and error. File descriptor 3 is the first descriptor available for other things (like duplicating one of the others or referring to a stream from or to a file etc.) You would use these numbers anywhere where the number that designates a file descriptor is expected. In the shell, that would mostly be in redirections, i.e., as in `>&2`, but also in the `-t` test.

Answer (score -1):

According to instruction from https://github.com/sickill/stderred you should add to your script

```
export LD_PRELOAD="/path/to/stderred/\$LIB/libstderred.so${LD_PRELOAD:+:$LD_PRELOAD}"
```

where the `$LIB` may should be substituted by hand onto you architecture